# jQuery "ready"-like event possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like this:

```
$("#container").otherBind("foo-content-loaded", function() {alert("immediate or later!");});
```

"foo-content-loaded" is a custom event I'm firing only once ever.  `otherBind` is similar to `$.ready()`, such that the handler fires right away if the event has already been triggered or else it acts like a regular event.

how would otherBind() be defined?  Incidently, what's the cool CS name for this type of binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of firing a custom event, use a [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

// when content loaded, resolve the Deferred:
deferred.resolve();
```

Elsewhere, you can add as many `done()` handlers as you like and have them called even if you add them after-the-fact:

```
deferred.promise().done(function () {
    // content was loaded at some point
});
```

If you're loading your content via `$.ajax`, you should note that `$.ajax` calls already return a Promise interface (a restricted interface for Deferreds) to which you can attach `done()` handlers.

Comment: Hmmm.  I was blind but now I see.  Deferreds are blowing my mind.  They make Ajax calls so much cleaner.  Thanks!